# Problem in Subversion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn

I Implement subversion for first time for test in 2 computers.In a Client Computer I work in a working copy of a project.in this project i add a **Devxcomponent (button)** in my form and then commit project and send newly version on the server.When I open an updated working copy of project in server ,my project has an error in references Section and show a yellow error in my new dll component.how can i fix this problem?

Comment: What language/tool are you doing this in ? did you say you checked in in one system and tried to checkout in the other code and you see a error ? (I am just getting a feel this is not something specific to svn)

Comment: Sorry.I Use Subversion for my C# project ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check if you're not using any third-party dll. If so, it must be commited as well. You can create a folder named dll and add your button dll on it. Commit that folder. When you update in server, just add the reference again to that dll.

Answer (score 1):

Did you miss checking in the dll reference? You must do a `svn add` on files that you add to your project as references and commit them as well. Also you say you added the Devxcomponent (button) - did that involve adding a new file? You have to add that as well.

Since you are using TortoiseSVN:

Right click on your project -> TortoiseSVN -> Check for Modifications.

Look for non-versioned items. If the file / folder is non-versioned which is needed by your project, right click on it and click Add and then commit.

Comment: I Try to add a dll,but i can not see dll files in list(Check for Modification or Add) ...

Comment: You must provide more details. Are you doing the check for modifications from the root folder of your project?

Comment: Yes, I Checked it But I Can Not See Dll Component i Added to Refrence in modifications ...

Comment: In the lower left, there are set of check boxes. Make sure you have checked the "Show unversioned files" one.